# Sending the file from bot to user(1:1)

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, botkit

I am new to development in teams and botkit. There is a bot that is up and running on Teams.
I want to share a file generated by the bot to the user(send a file from bot to the user) on teams. I have read the [Microsoft-teams document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4). According to which first step is to send a Message requesting permission to upload which I am able to complete successfully. Below is the code, I have used to show the card to the user to ask for permission.

```js
    controller.hears('download', ['message_received', 'direct_message', 'direct_mention'], function (bot, message) {
        var reply = {  text:"" ,attachments: [] }
        var ticketObj = {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.consent",
            "name": "result.txt",
            "content": {
                "description": "Text recognized from image",
                "sizeInBytes": 4348,
                "acceptContext": {
                    "resultId": "1a1e318d-8496-471b-9612-720ee4b1b592"
                },
                "declineContext": {
                    "resultId": "1a1e318d-8496-471b-9612-720ee4b1b592"
                }
            }
        }
        reply.attachments.push(ticketObj)
        bot.reply(message, reply)
    })
```

[image: Card shown for acceptance]

According to the [Microsoft-teams document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4), when the user will click on accept button, the bot will receive an Invoke activity with a location URL.
But, when I click on the accept, nothing goes to my bot. It shows the error message: "This card action is not supported".

How to provide support for this card action?

[image]

Comment: Could you please follow this sample(https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload) and check if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Is your issue resolved or are you still looking for any help?

Comment: I figured out that the issue is of uploading the manifest.json.
So, yes the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from comment section for more visibility:

Issue is resolved now. The issue was of uploading the manifest.json.

> To send and receive files in the bot, set the supportsFiles property
> in the manifest to true. This property is described in the bots
> section of the Manifest reference.
>
> The definition looks like this, "supportsFiles": true. If the bot does
> not enable supportsFiles, the features listed in this section do not
> work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4#configure-the-bot-to-support-files

Sample Link:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/56.teams-file-upload